# Cloud Messaging of Flutter - Can't send message any device with token

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

when I want to send test message with token from firebase console, it works very well in debug mode. But in release mode, I cannot send a message to the device with token. Anyone having problems with this?

Comment: Are you testing it with latest fresh FCM token?

Comment: android or ios?

Comment: not working on android, i can't test it ios